# effectively comparing two arrays of different size

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

I have two arrays (`data` and `final`) and I would like to compare both arrays and return (`out`) the element in `data` which are not in `final`

data:

```
x        y      z
10.2    15.2    25.2
15.2    17.2    40.2
12.2    13.2    5.2
14.2    14.2    34.2
12.2    12.2    56.2
13.2    17.2    32.2
11.2    13.2    21.2
```

final:

```
x        y      z
15.2    17.2    40.2
14.2    14.2    34.2
12.2    12.2    56.2
```

out:

```
x        y      z
10.2    15.2    25.2
12.2    13.2    5.2
13.2    17.2    32.2
11.2    13.2    21.2
```

This is what I have done,

```
out = [np.column_stack(data[k]) for k in range(len(data)) if data[k] not in final]
out = np.vstack(out)
```

Problem

The problem I have is, I have to perform this action of getting my `out` about 10000 times (the example is just one out of 10000) and as such speed is my major concern.

Is there an efficient way to perform this?

Comment: @Divakar, the np.ravel_multi_index works with integers. what if my data are of type float64

Comment: How many columns do you have in your actual case?

Comment: @Divakar, I have 3 columns for both `final` and `data`

Comment: Try working with set() and its differentiate function

Comment: Is it guaranteed that all rows from final would be in data?

Comment: @Divakar, Yes all rows from final would be in data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach -

```
def remrows(a, b): # remove rows from a based on b
    ab = np.row_stack((a,b))
    sidx = np.lexsort(ab.T)
    ab_sorted = ab[sidx]
    idx = np.flatnonzero((ab_sorted[1:] == ab_sorted[:-1]).all(1))
    return np.delete(a, sidx[idx], axis=0)
```

If you want to account for some tolerance when comparing those floating-pt values, you might want to use `np.isclose()` instead of `==` at the `idx` step.

Sample run -

```
In [222]: a = np.random.randint(111,999,(10,3)).astype(float)/10.0

In [223]: a
Out[223]: 
array([[ 51.3,  66.3,  58.8],
       [ 24.3,  40.6,  37.8],
       [ 94.7,  28.8,  69.3],
       [ 21.8,  48.3,  57.5],
       [ 87.1,  81.9,  27.9],
       [ 14.2,  36.4,  22.2],
       [ 56.7,  58.7,  16.2],
       [ 66.2,  99.1,  62.5],
       [ 75.1,  27.8,  34.4],
       [ 59.7,  73.8,  22.3]])

In [224]: b = a[[1,3,5]]

In [225]: remrows(a, b)
Out[225]: 
array([[ 51.3,  66.3,  58.8],
       [ 94.7,  28.8,  69.3],
       [ 87.1,  81.9,  27.9],
       [ 56.7,  58.7,  16.2],
       [ 66.2,  99.1,  62.5],
       [ 75.1,  27.8,  34.4],
       [ 59.7,  73.8,  22.3]])
```